# Linux path/dependencies handling

Tags: linux, ubuntu, path, dependencies, ubuntu-15.04

I am a --user(no sudo access) on a ubuntu 15.04 server.

I have to type this command every time I login to the 15.04 ubuntu server:

```
>> export PATH="/usr/local/cuda/bin:$PATH"
>> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

Can I place these commands somewhere such that I don't have to type them every time I access the server?
I have tried writing them in my .bashrc, but that didn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the values in your **~/.profile** file

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Persistent_environment_variables